# Is it possible to do automated testing with detox outside of the target application?

Tags: android, react-native, testing, automated-tests, detox

I have built a react-native application and am trying to build a few specific end-to-end tests on the android side. For this, I have setup detox. Unfortunately, to test properly, I need to see how the application responds when the user is performing actions outside of the target application.

e.g. I need to automate click A within target application A, click android home button, swipe right on screen and then open application B. Application A should then open itself and the test can confirm if it has opened to the right screen.

Is something like this possible within Detox? If not, are there any frameworks that would allow me to test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are wanting to do is use something called 'Appium' instead of 'Detox'. This is due to Appium interfacing with the androids uiAutomator API which allows automation and testing outside of a single application, Detox is more for testing the behaviour within the application itself rather than outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is now [somewhat supported](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/api/device#devicegetuidevice-android-only) in Detox:

> `device.getUiDevice()`
>
> Exposes UiAutomator’s UiDevice API. This is not a part of the official Detox API, it may break and change whenever an update to UiDevice or UiAutomator Gradle dependencies (androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator) is introduced.